# QuickStart template updates to V4.0.0

Tags: identityserver4

Any word on when updates will be available for IdentityServer4's QuickStart examples?  Upgraded to V4 from 3.1 today, but there are breaking changes I can't find documentation for.  Tried to update the templates:

```
dotnet new --force -i IdentityServer4.Templates
```

but they're still using the previous version.

Comment: The version is announced on the [website of Dominick](https://leastprivilege.com/2020/06/19/announcing-identityserver4-v4-0/) including a link to the [release notes](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/releases/tag/4.0.0) where you can find information about the (breaking) changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the github repo, the Quickstart UI has been updated to v4.
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI

Also looks like the dotnet cli templates have been updated to v4 as well, projects are now using IdentityServer4 packages version 4.0.0.

From reading dominick baier's twitter post (https://twitter.com/leastprivilege/status/1276809943954440194) migrating from 3.1 to 4 will require updating the database schema with the scripts provided below.
https://github.com/RockSolidKnowledge/IdentityServer4.Migration.Scripts/tree/CreateScripts

Comment: This is a nice complete guide for the database migration from v.3.x to v.4.x

https://www.identityserver.com/articles/migrating-your-identityserver4-v3-database-to-identityserver4-v4